# One of my js files is not being bundled in my production build (dist folder)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I am creating a Vue app (using Vite), and I like to have my .js functions in different files inside a `scripts` folder. I have started recently so for the time being I only have one .js file appart from the main.js that comes with Vue.

When I build the application to deploy it, it seems that this .js file is not included in the bundle, so the deployed app cannot use it's functions.

How could I make the `npm run build` command include this local .js file that I am using (and it works when running the app in localhost), so that the deployed app works as expected? Am I missing something in where local files should be put inside the project files tree?

I have checked other questions regarding this, and also the official documentation, but maybe due to my lack of experience with Vue I haven't found the answer or haven't understood it.

Comment: You might need to use some bundle third party plugin